# Open Display Settings or Run Dialog Box using Python

Tags: python, windows

How can I open `RunDialogBox` or `Display settings` using `Python`?

I found a way to open `Display settings` using `Run Dialog box` (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), just type in `ms-settings:display`.

With cmd you can type `explorer.exe shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}`, or with Powershell `(New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application").FileRun()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple option is to run the cmd command from Python:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['explorer.exe', 'shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}'])
```

As for the Display settings, that's also achievable in a similar way:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['control.exe', 'desk.cpl'])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73450016/find-how-many-monitors-computer-is-using-with-python-or-cmd

Answer (score 1):

The `ms-settings:` is a URI scheme, as per [`Launch the Windows Settings app`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).

Therefore you can just use the [`webbrowser`](https://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module, which is part of Python's standard library, to open the Display Settings window.

```py
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("ms-settings:display")
```